# Check for duplicate column names in an SQL query

Tags: programming, mysql, sql

I have a rather long SQL (MySQL flavor) query and want to check if different fields queries have the same name (or alias) like `SELECT a, a ...`. Any software for this?

I use Linux.

Comment: Just curios. Is this a major  problem? If you intend to display it, the duplication will be immediately visually apparent. If not, then it doesn’t matter whether the code access field `a` the identical value from the other field `a`? Obviously, you had a problem, or you wouldn't ask. Personally, I don’t see the need for a tool, but, if you want one, that’s fine. Other than a (minor, IMO) performance hit, is this a big thing, which I am unaware of? I am a causal MySql user & always keen to learn

Comment: @Mawg I have solved the problem simply highlighting a word in a text editor. All duplicates are highlighted by a feature of the editor. This solves the problem for me.

Comment: @Mawg The essence of the problem was not to create a Perl code with messed field names, when two fields are assigned by the same name, so damaging the logic of my program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No software needed.  Create a dummy view using your query.  If it works, you're good, because views don't support multiple columns with the same name.

`CREATE VIEW v1 AS SELECT ...` ...your query.  If there are duplicate column names, this fails... and gives you one of the duplicate names.

```
ERROR 1060 (42S21): Duplicate column name 'foo'
```

Note also that if you have a client library that understands it, a `SELECT` query returning multiple columns with the same name is not technically invalid in MySQL, which is why such a query doesn't throw an error if you simply execute it.  Not a good thing to do, typically, but not technically invalid.

Comment: Interestingly, neither http://developer.mimer.se/validator/index.htm nor https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/ see this as a problem, but they only check syntax and, as you dsay, that is valid syntax.Just thought I'd throw them in for folks who have never heard of them